# Manga with a prodigal martial artist whose body is limited to half power by his father

Tags: aiki

I read a martial arts manga set in present day where a prodigal martial artist fights lots of enemies as they come along. The main character is almost unbeatable but in his youth was a bad person and so one night, while he was sleeping, his father affected his joints to limit his power to half. As stronger enemies come along he starts having trouble in his limited state and begins seeing an old lady who painfully repairs his joints to remove those limits. I'd really appreciate help finding this thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Aiki](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=1802).

> Kunitoshi Joukyuu is a lazy ass, good for nothing pervert. **Who also happens to be a supposed genius master of Aikido, the strongest in the world, if not because his father sealed away most of his abilities before dying.**
>
> So now he's stuck trying to find a way to rid himself of the "curse" that had been put on him all the while getting involved in fights with beautiful high-school girls who are a part of a power-struggle over a school.
>
> But none ever suspected the true sadistic monster that hides underneath the calm and bored face he usually wears.
>
> Who will be in greater trouble? The girls, or Joukyuu?

Comment: You're the boss, mate. Cheers!